# SignNow API Integration With Ms Access VBA

Tags: vba, api, ms-access, signnow

I have a sandbox account to test the API on signnow.
im testing the API step by step to make sure that i can make the integration using Access VBA.

I was able to get the Access Token Using this Code:

```
   Private Sub Command5_Click()
 sUrl = "https://api-eval.signnow.com/oauth2/token"
    sUsername = "rami_jebara@hotmail.com"
    sPassword = "XXXXXXXX"
    AsToken = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    sgrant_type = "password"
    sscope = "*"
    sbody = "username=" & sUsername & "&password=" & sPassword & "&grant_type=" & sgrant_type & "&scope=" & sscope

    ' Make the request
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
        .Open "Post", sUrl, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "basic " & AsToken
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .Send sbody
        Debug.Print .responseText
        Debug.Print .GetAllResponseHeaders
        TempVars.Add "ACToken", .responseText
        Me.Requery
        Text0.Requery
    End With
End Sub
```

I Grant the Access Token Successfully

But Now I Stucked on Uploading a PDF file from Ms Access to Signnow
Below the Code im Using

```
 Option Compare Database

Private Function GetFileSize(fileFullPath As String) As Long

    Dim lngFSize As Long, lngDSize As Long
    Dim oFO As Object, OFS As Object

    lngFSize = 0
    Set OFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If OFS.FileExists(fileFullPath) Then
        Set oFO = OFS.getFile(fileFullPath)
        GetFileSize = 31812
    Else
        GetFileSize = 0
    End If

    Set oFO = Nothing
    Set OFS = Nothing
End Function
Private Function ReadBinary(strFilePath As String)
    Dim ado As Object, bytFile
    Set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    ado.Type = 1
    ado.Open
    ado.LoadFromFile strFilePath
    bytFile = ado.Read
    ado.Close

    ReadBinary = bytFile

    Set ado = Nothing
End Function


Private Function toArray(str)
    Dim ado As Object
     Set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
     ado.Type = 2
     ado.Charset = "_autodetect"
     ado.Open
     ado.WriteText (str)
     ado.Position = 0
     ado.Type = 1
     toArray = ado.Read()
     Set ado = Nothing
End Function


Function POST_multipart_form_data(filePath As String)

    Dim oFields As Object, ado As Object
    Dim sBoundary As String, sPayLoad As String
    Dim fileType As String, fileExtn As String, fileName As String
    Dim sName As Variant

    fileName = Right(filePath, Len(filePath) - InStrRev(filePath, "\"))
    fileExtn = Right(filePath, Len(fileName) - InStrRev(fileName, "."))

    Select Case fileExtn
     Case "pdf"
        fileType = "application/pdf"
     Case "jpg"
        fileType = "image/jpeg"
     Case "txt"
        fileType = "text/plain"
    End Select


    sBoundary = String(27, "-")
    sPayLoad = ""


    sPayLoad = sPayLoad & "--" & sBoundary & vbCrLf
    sPayLoad = sPayLoad & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""file""; " & "filename=""" & fileName & """" & vbCrLf
    sPayLoad = sPayLoad & "Content-Type: " & fileType & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & vbCrLf



     sPayLoad = sPayLoad & "--" & sBoundary & "--"


      Set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
      ado.Type = 1
      ado.Open
      ado.Write toArray(sPayLoad)
      ado.Write ReadBinary(filePath)
      ado.Position = 0

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", "https://api-eval.signnow.com/document", False
        .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "bearer " & "e3c9d47d08199cf8a4baa6529c8dc3349c0f76380c3a0fecf0842ddd600711aa"
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & sBoundary
        .Send (ado.Read())
        MsgBox .responseText
    End With

End Function
```

it is returning this Error

```
  {
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": 66048,
            "message": "Unable to upload pdf document, pdf document headers are malformed"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now i have been working on this error for two weeks i need a help.
Thanks in Advance